# How can I get a property projection filtered by same query used in $in operator in MongoDB using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've this documents

```
User A: {_id: xxxx, id: A, contacts: ['B', 'C'] }
    
User B:  {   _id: xxxx,   id: B,   contacts: ['A', 'D'] }

User C: {   _id: xxxx,   id: C,   contacts: ['D'] }
       
User D:  {   _id: xxxx,   id: D,   contacts: ['A', 'B'] }
```

My current code:

```
User.find({contacts: { $in: ['A', 'B']}}, { _id: 0, id: 1, contacts: 1})
```

Result of this:

```
[{
   _id: xxxx,
   id: A,
   contacts: ['B', 'C']
},{
   _id: xxxx,
   id: B,
   contacts: ['A', 'D']
},{
   _id: xxxx,
   id: D,
   contacts: ['A', 'B']
}]
```

**Expected Result:** (I just want property contacts to be filtered by query array --> in this case, [A, B])

```
[{
   _id: xxxx,
   id: A,
   contacts: ['B']
},{
   _id: xxxx,
   id: B,
   contacts: ['A']
},{
   _id: xxxx,
   id: D,
   contacts: ['A', 'B']
}]
```

I've tried with aggregation with same result.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try aggregation projection operators starting from MongoDB 4.4,

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `contacts` array and filter as per input array

```
db.collection.find({ contacts: { $in: ["A", "B"] } },
{
  _id: 0,
  id: 1,
  contacts: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$contacts",
      cond: { $in: ["$$this", ["A", "B"]] }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KIsKpuLWk_K)